# How to run a single JUnit test method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

In a JUnit test case with multiple @Test annotations, how does one selectively run tests ?

For e.g., from the following code, how does one run just one test method ?

```
   @Test
   public void testHelloEmpty() 
   {
      assertEquals(h.getName(),"");
      assertEquals(h.getMessage(),"Hello!");
   }

   @Test
   public void testHelloWorld() 
   {
      // h.setName("World");
      assertEquals(h.getName(),"World");
      assertEquals(h.getMessage(),"Hello World!");
   }
```

I have tried to just highlight one @Test method and tried to run it, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Which build tool are you using for running the tests?

Comment: @StefanBirkner I am using maven but I am not interested in mvn tests. Just to be able to select one of the @ Test methods, right click in eclipse and run as unit test

Comment: Something like in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/9288107/2570213 just I want to be able to do it from eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For running a single test case in Eclipse (as per your last comment):

- Go to Run (the green forward arrow button) -> Run Configurations.
- Right click on JUnit, and select new.
- Fill in your test case and test method (the Search button is really helpful here).
- Click Run.

Comment: Still seems to be the same in 2015. Holy cow... And I'm expected to do that for each single method I want to run? That probably takes longer than running all test together. Has any Eclipse developer ever seen how this works in Visual Studio? It's two clicks for any test at any time - no need for a configuration. I leave this comment in hope that someone implements this in Eclipse the same way.

Comment: @Thomas it's possible to do this in newer eclipse versions, see other answers below.

Comment: InitializationError [Runner:JUnit 4] (0,00s)

Answer (score 9):

It seems that now days (Eclispse 4.4.0) this can be done easily.

If you place the caret at the head of the definition of a test case method, issue the *Run* or *Debug* command (menu or <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), then the JUnit plugin runs only that test case.

(If you on the other hand place the caret in the *body* of a method then all the test cases in that class are run.)

Some more tips for running JUnit tests:

- The *Go to Previous/Next Member* commands can be used to quickly move the caret to the head of the definition of a method with the keyboard. The default key bindings are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.
- If the *Run* or *Debug* commands are issued when the *Debug*, *JUnit* or *Console* views are active, then Eclipse will run the last run configuration. This can be used to re-run your single test case without having to navigate back to the editor.
- Running a particular run configuration can be done by navigating the *Run* menu: <kbd>Alt + R</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, number key.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is label your tests as belonging to different [JUnit Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) and then run just those from one or more categories and not all tests, using the `@RunWith` and `@Categories` annotations.  It's how I've done it in the past.  In your case, you may have a category with just one test.

See examples:

[Running benchmark methods in a JUnit test class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755389/running-benchmark-methods-in-a-junit-test-class)

[How to run all tests belonging to a certain Category in JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176570/how-to-run-all-tests-belonging-to-a-certain-category-in-junit-4/2176791#)

Answer (score 1):

Put the cursor on the method name, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>T</kbd>. This will run the test method as JUnit test.

Note: do not put the cursor insode the method. This will run all methods in the class. It must be on the method declaration.

Also note: `@BeforeClass` test setups might not be executed in case you organize your tests in test suites.